# MySQL to PostgreSQL conversion and data synchronisation

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-migration

I have a relatively large MySQL database (over 300 tables) which I desperately need to convert to PostgreSQL and synchronise data between the two databases if not real time then something close to it. Ideally I need a bi-directional data sync, or at least one directional - MySQL to Postgres sync.

I have managed to convert the database and import the data, but synchronisation seems to be a real problem.

[This solution](http://dbconvert.com/convert-mysql-to-postgresql-sync.php?DB=3) from DBConvert should supposedly do exactly that. After many days of trying to make it work I gave up. They don't even have a linux client which is strange considering that absolute majority of MySQL and Postgres database would run on linux servers.

Is there an alternative to DBConvert's solution that would do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Pentaho ETL tools Kettle and its client interface, Spoon. http://kettle.pentaho.com

Comment: I couldn't find any references of MySQL to PostgreSQL conversion or synchronisation in this link. What exactly is it? Screenshots are done in Windows XP, last release almost a year ago...

Comment: Its one of the most capable Extract-Transform-Load tools in the open source space. It supports Postgres, MySQL, and others. Extensively documented at http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Latest+Pentaho+Data+Integration+%28aka+Kettle%29+Documentation

Comment: Oh, and the client is based on Java, so it runs on (and comes with a startup script for) linux.

Answer (score 0):

boy, you have a job ahead of you in terms of bidirectional synchronization.  This is hard on the best of days, and it poses a lot of problems.

The tool I would look at first, actually, would be [RubyRep](http://www.rubyrep.org/).  This gives you a basic framework for replication between your databases, and it supports a number of RDBMS's.

The second thing you have to think about is what you are actually doing and why this is a really bad idea.  Your biggest issue is conflict resolution and managing what happens if two different people update the same record on the different db's.  This is not a trivial problem and it requires thinking through the actual workflows and scenarios carefully.